# Slow when joining with view

Tags: performance, postgresql, join, view

I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.4.4`

The view `V_OpenCourse_WithTC`

```
 SELECT x1.id,
    (x1.data ->> 'subject_id'::text)::bigint AS subject_id,
    x2.data ->> 'program_session'::text AS program_session,
    (x2.data ->> 'semester_id'::text)::bigint AS semester_id,
    (x2.data ->> 'curriculum_id'::text)::bigint AS curriculum_id,
    (x3.data ->> 'major_id'::text)::bigint AS major_id
   FROM open_courses x1
     JOIN trimester_courses x2 ON ((x1.data ->> 'trimester_course_id'::text)::bigint) = x2.id
     JOIN tags x3 ON ((x2.data ->> 'curriculum_id'::text)::bigint) = x3.id AND (x3.data ->> 'type'::text) = 'curriculum'::text
  WHERE x1.is_deleted = false;
```

SELECT from that view = fast

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM V_OpenCourse_WithTC;
                                                               QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=92.89..251.57 rows=18 width=382) (actual time=2.086..9.478 rows=3832 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (((x1.data ->> 'trimester_course_id'::text))::bigint = x2.id)
   ->  Seq Scan on open_courses x1  (cost=0.00..128.00 rows=3991 width=105) (actual time=0.007..0.815 rows=3991 loops=1)
         Filter: (NOT is_deleted)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 9
   ->  Hash  (cost=92.81..92.81 rows=6 width=285) (actual time=2.067..2.067 rows=1405 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 558kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=31.16..92.81 rows=6 width=285) (actual time=0.297..1.508 rows=1405 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (((x2.data ->> 'curriculum_id'::text))::bigint = x3.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on trimester_courses x2  (cost=0.00..51.05 rows=1405 width=131) (actual time=0.003..0.160 rows=1405 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=31.12..31.12 rows=3 width=162) (actual time=0.287..0.287 rows=101 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 25kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on tags x3  (cost=0.00..31.12 rows=3 width=162) (actual time=0.168..0.264 rows=101 loops=1)
                           Filter: ((data ->> 'type'::text) = 'curriculum'::text)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 574
 Planning time: 0.226 ms
 Execution time: 9.655 ms
(17 rows)
```

SELECT FROM the main table = fast

```
explain analyze 
    SELECT id, data->>'open_course_id' oc_id
    FROM student_credits 
    WHERE (data->>'student_id')::BIGINT = '5500'

                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on student_credits  (cost=0.00..14631.51 rows=910 width=396) (actual time=37.330..71.647 rows=33 loops=1)
   Filter: (((data ->> 'student_id'::text))::bigint = 5500::bigint)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 181979
 Planning time: 0.043 ms
 Execution time: 71.665 ms
```

## 1 SELECT with join manually without view = fast

```
explain analyze 
SELECT x1.id
FROM student_credits x1
    JOIN course_classes x2
        ON (x1.data->>'course_class_id')::BIGINT = x2.id
    JOIN open_courses x3
        ON (x2.data->>'open_course_id')::BIGINT = x3.id
    JOIN trimester_courses x4
        ON (x3.data->>'trimester_course_id')::BIGINT = x4.id
WHERE (x1.data->>'student_id')::BIGINT = '5500'
        AND x4.data->>'semester_id' = '53'

                                                                     QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=1541.70..16177.81 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=80.254..80.254 rows=0 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (((x1.data ->> 'course_class_id'::text))::bigint = x2.id)
   ->  Seq Scan on student_credits x1  (cost=0.00..14629.24 rows=910 width=396) (actual time=25.195..72.745 rows=33 loops=1)
         Filter: (((data ->> 'student_id'::text))::bigint = 5500::bigint)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 181979
   ->  Hash  (cost=1541.08..1541.08 rows=50 width=8) (actual time=7.473..7.473 rows=814 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 32kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=216.61..1541.08 rows=50 width=8) (actual time=2.050..7.372 rows=814 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (((x2.data ->> 'open_course_id'::text))::bigint = x3.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on course_classes x2  (cost=0.00..1248.55 rows=10055 width=653) (actual time=0.002..0.946 rows=10055 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=216.36..216.36 rows=20 width=8) (actual time=2.038..2.038 rows=410 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=58.16..216.36 rows=20 width=8) (actual time=0.463..1.992 rows=410 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (((x3.data ->> 'trimester_course_id'::text))::bigint = x4.id)
                           ->  Seq Scan on open_courses x3  (cost=0.00..128.00 rows=4000 width=105) (actual time=0.002..0.315 rows=4000 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=58.08..58.08 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=0.447..0.447 rows=142 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 6kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on trimester_courses x4  (cost=0.00..58.08 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.431 rows=142 loops=1)
                                       Filter: ((data ->> 'semester_id'::text) = '53'::text)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 1263
 Planning time: 0.234 ms
 Execution time: 80.296 ms
(22 rows)
```

## 2 SELECT with WHERE IN from view = fast

```
explain analyze
SELECT x1.id
FROM student_credits x1
WHERE (x1.data->>'student_id')::BIGINT = '5500'
        AND (x1.data->>'open_course_id')::BIGINT IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM V_OpenCourse_WithTC
                WHERE semester_id = '53'
        )

                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=65.19..14905.52 rows=455 width=8) (actual time=87.144..87.144 rows=0 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (((x1.data ->> 'open_course_id'::text))::bigint = x1_1.id)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 13233
   ->  Seq Scan on student_credits x1  (cost=0.00..14629.24 rows=910 width=396) (actual time=23.892..71.475 rows=33 loops=1)
         Filter: (((data ->> 'student_id'::text))::bigint = 5500::bigint)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 181979
   ->  Materialize  (cost=65.19..255.81 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.021..0.420 rows=401 loops=33)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=65.19..255.80 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.680..13.356 rows=401 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (((x2.data ->> 'curriculum_id'::text))::bigint = x3.id)
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 40100
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=65.19..223.32 rows=20 width=131) (actual time=0.501..2.150 rows=401 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (((x1_1.data ->> 'trimester_course_id'::text))::bigint = x2.id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on open_courses x1_1  (cost=0.00..128.00 rows=3991 width=105) (actual time=0.006..0.580 rows=3991 loops=1)
                           Filter: (NOT is_deleted)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 9
                     ->  Hash  (cost=65.10..65.10 rows=7 width=131) (actual time=0.481..0.481 rows=142 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 23kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on trimester_courses x2  (cost=0.00..65.10 rows=7 width=131) (actual time=0.009..0.454 rows=142 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (((data ->> 'semester_id'::text))::bigint = 53::bigint)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1263
               ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..31.14 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.004 rows=101 loops=401)
                     ->  Seq Scan on tags x3  (cost=0.00..31.12 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.114..0.208 rows=101 loops=1)
                           Filter: ((data ->> 'type'::text) = 'curriculum'::text)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 574
 Planning time: 0.320 ms
 Execution time: 87.188 ms
(26 rows)
```

## 3 SELECT with JOIN to view = slow

```
explain analyze
SELECT x1.id
FROM student_credits x1
, V_OpenCourse_WithTC x2
WHERE (x1.data->>'student_id')::BIGINT = '5500'
        AND x2.semester_id = '53'
        AND (x1.data->>'open_course_id')::BIGINT = x2.id

                                                              QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=177.89..14951.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10155.277..10155.277 rows=0 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (((x1_1.data ->> 'trimester_course_id'::text))::bigint = x2.id)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..96.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.221..5.487 rows=142 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (((x2.data ->> 'curriculum_id'::text))::bigint = x3.id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 14200
         ->  Seq Scan on trimester_courses x2  (cost=0.00..65.10 rows=7 width=131) (actual time=0.013..0.637 rows=142 loops=1)
               Filter: (((data ->> 'semester_id'::text))::bigint = 53::bigint)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1263
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..31.14 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.006 rows=101 loops=142)
               ->  Seq Scan on tags x3  (cost=0.00..31.12 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.146..0.225 rows=101 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((data ->> 'type'::text) = 'curriculum'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 574
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=177.89..14836.68 rows=908 width=105) (actual time=71.475..71.475 rows=0 loops=142)
         Hash Cond: (((x1.data ->> 'open_course_id'::text))::bigint = x1_1.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on student_credits x1  (cost=0.00..14629.24 rows=910 width=396) (actual time=36.517..71.458 rows=33 loops=142)
               Filter: (((data ->> 'student_id'::text))::bigint = 5500::bigint)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 181979
         ->  Hash  (cost=128.00..128.00 rows=3991 width=105) (actual time=1.428..1.428 rows=3991 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 549kB
               ->  Seq Scan on open_courses x1_1  (cost=0.00..128.00 rows=3991 width=105) (actual time=0.005..0.736 rows=3991 loops=1)
                     Filter: (NOT is_deleted)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 9
 Planning time: 0.309 ms
 Execution time: 10155.321 ms
(24 rows)
```

## 4 SELECT with JOIN to a filtered view = slow

```
explain analyze 
SELECT x1.id    
FROM student_credits x1
JOIN (
SELECT * FROM V_OpenCourse_WithTC 
        WHERE semester_id = '53'
     ) x2 
        ON (x1.data->>'open_course_id')::BIGINT = x2.id 
WHERE (x1.data->>'student_id')::BIGINT = '5500'

                                                              QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=177.89..14951.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10229.667..10229.667 rows=0 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (((x1_1.data ->> 'trimester_course_id'::text))::bigint = x2.id)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..96.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.218..5.623 rows=142 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (((x2.data ->> 'curriculum_id'::text))::bigint = x3.id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 14200
         ->  Seq Scan on trimester_courses x2  (cost=0.00..65.10 rows=7 width=131) (actual time=0.014..0.705 rows=142 loops=1)
               Filter: (((data ->> 'semester_id'::text))::bigint = 53::bigint)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1263
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..31.14 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.006 rows=101 loops=142)
               ->  Seq Scan on tags x3  (cost=0.00..31.12 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.142..0.229 rows=101 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((data ->> 'type'::text) = 'curriculum'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 574
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=177.89..14836.68 rows=908 width=105) (actual time=71.998..71.998 rows=0 loops=142)
         Hash Cond: (((x1.data ->> 'open_course_id'::text))::bigint = x1_1.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on student_credits x1  (cost=0.00..14629.24 rows=910 width=396) (actual time=36.812..71.981 rows=33 loops=142)
               Filter: (((data ->> 'student_id'::text))::bigint = 5500::bigint)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 181979
         ->  Hash  (cost=128.00..128.00 rows=3991 width=105) (actual time=1.401..1.401 rows=3991 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 549kB
               ->  Seq Scan on open_courses x1_1  (cost=0.00..128.00 rows=3991 width=105) (actual time=0.005..0.681 rows=3991 loops=1)
                     Filter: (NOT is_deleted)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 9
 Planning time: 0.313 ms
 Execution time: 10229.720 ms
(24 rows)
```

## 5 SELECT from both filtered first = slow

```
explain analyze
SELECT x1.id    
FROM ( 
    SELECT id, data->>'open_course_id' oc_id
    FROM student_credits 
    WHERE (data->>'student_id')::BIGINT = '5500'
) x1
JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM V_OpenCourse_WithTC 
        WHERE semester_id = '53'
) x2 ON x1.oc_id::BIGINT = x2.id  

                                                             QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=177.89..14951.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10251.851..10251.851 rows=0 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (((x1.data ->> 'trimester_course_id'::text))::bigint = x2.id)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..96.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.222..5.581 rows=142 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (((x2.data ->> 'curriculum_id'::text))::bigint = x3.id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 14200
         ->  Seq Scan on trimester_courses x2  (cost=0.00..65.10 rows=7 width=131) (actual time=0.012..0.678 rows=142 loops=1)
               Filter: (((data ->> 'semester_id'::text))::bigint = 53::bigint)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1263
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..31.14 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.007 rows=101 loops=142)
               ->  Seq Scan on tags x3  (cost=0.00..31.12 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.140..0.227 rows=101 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((data ->> 'type'::text) = 'curriculum'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 574
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=177.89..14836.68 rows=908 width=105) (actual time=72.154..72.154 rows=0 loops=142)
         Hash Cond: (((student_credits.data ->> 'open_course_id'::text))::bigint = x1.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on student_credits  (cost=0.00..14629.24 rows=910 width=396) (actual time=36.960..72.137 rows=33 loops=142)
               Filter: (((data ->> 'student_id'::text))::bigint = 5500::bigint)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 181979
         ->  Hash  (cost=128.00..128.00 rows=3991 width=105) (actual time=1.406..1.406 rows=3991 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 549kB
               ->  Seq Scan on open_courses x1  (cost=0.00..128.00 rows=3991 width=105) (actual time=0.005..0.656 rows=3991 loops=1)
                     Filter: (NOT is_deleted)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 9
 Planning time: 0.312 ms
 Execution time: 10251.902 ms
(24 rows)
```

the question is, why query JOIN with view (3-5), so slow in this case?

Comment: 1) `Filter: (((data ->> 'semester_id'::text))::bigint = 53::bigint)` You are relating a text field (cast to integer) to an integer field.[ the same for `Filter: (((data ->> 'student_id'::text))::bigint = 5500::bigint)` )  2) your statistics are of (at least for one join) and 3) you are probably missing an index on one of the joined text fileds. 4) is (1) above caused by an EAV model and/or an ORM framework?

Comment: 1) all data field are always in jsonb format, so to convert it to integer I use `::BIGINT` | 2) yes, i make some mistake by misplacing `open_courses` with `student_credits` and vice versa, but that's not the point | 3) data uses `GIN` index, id is primary key, so no additional index needed. | 4) no, it's plain SQL